# Unity 3d & C#, if gameObject != this

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, this

I have this code:

```
public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject[] planets;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        planets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Planet");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach (GameObject planet in planets)
        {
            if (planet != this)
            {
                //do things
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I have a problem with "if (planet != this)..." what I expect to occur is that if planets[index] ==  the gameObject then "planet != this" will return false. But this is not working, how can I fix it?

Comment: did you try `!object.ReferenceEquals(planet, this)`?

Comment: `this` is a special keyword referring to the instance of your current object.  In this case an instance of `Gravity`.  When you call `someGravityObject.Update()`, `this` refers to `someGravityObject`.  Now, I'm assuming a `planet` cannot be a `Gravity` so `planet!=this` will always return true.

Comment: just wondering. How does "Gravity" have a tag "Planet"? Giving it another tag and you can get rid of the if alltogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a keyword which referes to the instance of the current object, in this case a `Gravity` class, so each `GameObject` object is different from a `Gravity` instance. You can do something like this, to access the attached `GameObject`:

```
foreach (GameObject planet in planets)
{
   if (planet != this.gameObject)
   {
      // Do magic stuff...
   } 
}
```